# Make grid item use remaining space like flex item with flex-grow: 1

Tags: html, css, css-grid

In a flexbox I can specify flex-grow:1 on a child to say it should take up the remaining space.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%
}
```

```html
<div style="display:flex;flex-direction:column;height:100%">     
  <div style="background-color:yellow;height:50px"></div>
  <div style="background-color:red;flex-grow:1"></div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to do the same thing with css grid? i.e. to specify against a child item that it should use remaining space **without** defining it explicitly using grid-template-rows?

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%
}
```

```html
<div style="display:grid;grid-template-columns:auto;height:100%">
  <div style="background-color:yellow;height:50px"></div>
  <!-- what to use instead of flex-grow:1? -->
  <div style="background-color:red;flex-grow:1;"></div>
</div>
```

The real scenario relates to a grid containing a runtime defined number of columns, and a runtime defined set of children some of which may be display:none.

Answer (score 0):

You could specify the row height with `grid-template-rows: min-content auto;`, which minimizes the first row and stretches the second.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%
}
```

```html
<div style="display:grid;grid-template-columns:auto;height:100%;grid-template-rows: min-content auto;">
  <div style="background-color:yellow;height:50px"></div>
  <div style="background-color:red;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but my question specifically stated "without defining it explicitly using grid-template-rows".